# printing to terminal using Applescripts through Python

Tags: python, terminal, applescript

I'm using python to run some Applescript scripts. I'd like to be able to print to the screen while in a "repeat" loop. A dumbed down example of what I'm currently doing is:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

##### My applescript script

scpt = '''                                                                                                                                            
set letters to {"A", "B", "C"}                                                                                                                        
repeat with theLetter in letters                                                                                                                      
     do shell script "echo " & theLetter                                                                                                              
end repeat                                                                                                                                            
'''

#### run the script
p = Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(scpt)
print stdout, stderr
```

Now, doing it this way only the last entry gets printed to the terminal (in this case "C"). Is there a way I can get it to print to the terminal during every iteration. I.e.

```
A
B
C
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the output going to stderr, then the following is the easiest way that I use:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

##### My applescript script

scpt = '''
set letters to {"A", "B", "C"}
repeat with theLetter in letters
     log theLetter
end repeat
'''

#### run the script
p = Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(scpt)
print stdout, stderr
```

This will then give you the following (note the leading space because of the empty stdout):

```
 A
B
C
```

The other option if using `log` is to just combine stdout and stderr, so you end up with:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

##### My applescript script

scpt = '''
set letters to {"A", "B", "C"}
repeat with theLetter in letters
     log theLetter
end repeat
'''

#### run the script
p = Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(scpt)
print stdout
```

Giving you:

```
A
B
C
```

Of course as this is using `communicate`, it'll only give you the output when the process is complete, if you wanted to show progress on screen, one way would be to not capture stderr at all, and let the Applescript print to stderr (using `log`), and have your Python output to stdout when it's done.